Plotting wavy curve in Mathematica
I want to create a geometry with a wavy circumference, as shown in the figure below.
This waviness depends on a parameter "n", and the equation for the curve is given as:
r[\[Phi]]:= R + B*Sin[n*\[Phi]];

where \[Phi] goes from 0 to 2*pi.
Can someone pleae help me to figure out how I can create this using Mathematica?
I know I should use ParametericRegion, but I am unsure how to do it.
Thanks in advance,

ParametricPlot[(4 + Sin[10 θ]) {Cos[θ],     Sin[θ]}, {θ, 0, 2 π}]

Gear Curve from Wolfram Math World.

Use PolarPlot:
ClearAll[plot];
plot[R_, B_, n_] := 
  PolarPlot[R + B*Sin[n*\[Phi]], {\[Phi], 0, 2 Pi}, Axes -> False, 
   PlotStyle -> {Thick, Black}];
plot[20, 1, 12]



Use Manipulate, e.g., Manipulate[PolarPlot[R + B*Sin[n*\[Phi]], {\[Phi], 0, 2 Pi}, Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Black}], {{R, 20}, 1, 20, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{B, 1}, 1, 5, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{n, 12}, 1, 50, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, SynchronousUpdating -> False, TrackedSymbols :> {R, B, n}]
